# Hexadecimal code in Visual Studio designer, Crystal Reports 13.0.5

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, crystal-reports

I have problem with Crystal Reports. I am using Visual Studio 2015 and Crystal Reports 13.0.5, Windows Server 2012 R2.

Runtime works fine, but I can see only hexadecimal code when I'm trying to open rpt files in designer. Thing is I can't change version of Crystal Reports, because every app is written on this version.

I have tried to find solutions in internet with no success. Also I have tried to reinstall both runtimes and dev version many times.

Any ideas what might be an issue ?

Tomek

Comment: If you right-click the file from the Solution Explorer and choose `Open With...` does that give you a sensible option to choose? If so, you can click `Set as Default` to ensure that it's opened that way by default.

Comment: Hello,
I have options to choose from and JSON Editor is set as default, I can't see Crystal Reports Viewer (I guess it should be called something like that) thou...
Should I install CR Viewer additionaly to CR for VS ? It seems weird for me to have to do that additionaly to CR for VS installation.

Comment: I don't know if installing CR Viewer would work, but it's worth a try...

Comment: I have found that CR for VS version 13.0.5.891 (which I am using) is not compatible with VS2015.
The problem is that I can't change runtime version (13.0.5.891) on my clients PCs, and when I am installing latest version of CR for VS on my PC I also need to change references in my apps (which I can't do according to my superior). So I need to have 13.0.5.891 runtime and some version of CR for VS which is compatible with VS2015 and have same libraries version so there is no need to change references... Any ideas if this is even possible ?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know if that is possible.